How to run Schema GlobalDescribe code as a Batch Job (or how to satisfy the governor limits)
I wrote this code to update the FLS Read, for a given Permission Set, across ALL Objects and ALL fields in my org. It definitely hits the 10001 Governor Limit when it tries to insert that many FieldPermissions records. When I call it from a Batch Job (see code below), I still get 10001 GL. Please advise.
public with sharing class FieldPermissionsUtility {

@future
public static void createFieldPermissions() {
    String INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID = '0PS1Y111000kddfZ';
    Set<String> fieldsWithPermReadTrue = new Set<String>();
    List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsList = new List<FieldPermissions>();
    List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsForInsert = new List<FieldPermissions>();

    fieldPermissionsList = [SELECT Id, Field 
                            FROM FieldPermissions 
                            WHERE ParentID =: INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID 
                            AND PermissionsRead = true];
    
    for (FieldPermissions fp : fieldPermissionsList) {
        fieldsWithPermReadTrue.add(fp.Field);
    }
    
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    for (String objectApiName : gd.keySet()) { // loop all objects
        System.debug('------- objectApiName: ' + objectApiName);
        Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = gd.get(objectApiName);
        System.debug('------- sobjectType: ' + sobjectType);

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = sobjectType.getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();

        for (String fieldApiName : objectFields.keySet()) { // loop all fields per object
            System.debug('>>>> fieldApiName: ' + fieldApiName);
            Schema.SObjectField sobjectField = objectFields.get(fieldApiName);
            String objectDotField = objectApiName + '.' + fieldApiName;
            
            if (!fieldsWithPermReadTrue.contains(objectDotField)) {
                 FieldPermissions newFP = new FieldPermissions();
                 newFP.ParentId = INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID;
                 newFP.SObjectType = objectApiName;
                 newFP.Field = objectDotField;
                 newFP.PermissionsRead = true;
                 fieldPermissionsForInsert.add(newFP);
            }
        }
    }
    Database.insert(fieldPermissionsForInsert, false);
}

}

And the batch job...
  public with sharing class PermissionSetUpdateBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
      // need to return something
      return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1');
   }

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> records){
    FieldPermissionsUtility.createFieldPermissions();
   }

   public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    // execute any post-processing operations
   }  
  }


I'm more familiar with Batch, and I was already handling complexity, so I stuck with it.Thanks sfdcfox and Nagendra for your support.
For each FLS on a particular Permission Set, there's a FieldPermissions record in the background. This script went through over 500 objects in my org, setting every settable field to Read. Combined with System Settings: View All Data and API access, and this Permission Set I created for him, my User can pull all needed data into an external data lake.
public with sharing class PermissionSetUpdateBatch implements Database.Stateful, Database.Batchable<String> {
private String INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID = [SELECT Id 
                                             FROM PermissionSet 
                                             WHERE Label = 'Integration Bot View All Records'
                                             LIMIT 1].Id;
private Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
private List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsList = [SELECT Id, Field 
                                                       FROM FieldPermissions 
                                                       WHERE ParentID =: INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID 
                                                       AND PermissionsRead = true];
private Set<String> fieldsWithPermReadTrue = new Set<String>();

public Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    System.debug('>>> INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID: ' + INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID);
    System.debug('>>> fieldPermissionsList: ' + fieldPermissionsList);
    
    for (FieldPermissions fp : fieldPermissionsList) {
        fieldsWithPermReadTrue.add(fp.Field);
    }
    System.debug('>>> fieldsWithPermReadTrue: ' + fieldsWithPermReadTrue);

    List<String> objApiNames;
    System.debug('>>> objApiNames: ' + objApiNames);
    if(Test.isRunningTest()){
        objApiNames = new List<String>();
        objApiNames.add('order');
    } else {
        objApiNames = new List<String>(globalDescribe.keySet());
    }
    return objApiNames;
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<String> objectApiNames){
    List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsForInsert = new List<FieldPermissions>();
    
    for (String objectApiName : objectApiNames) { // loop all SObject
        //EntityDefinition ed = (EntityDefinition)record;
        System.debug('------- objectApiName: ' + objectApiName);

        // get the describe for each individual object
        Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = globalDescribe.get(objectApiName);
        System.debug('------- sobjectType: ' + sobjectType);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = sobjectType.getDescribe();
        
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();

        for (String fieldApiName : objectFields.keySet()) { // loop all fields per object
            System.debug('>>>> fieldApiName: ' + fieldApiName);
            Schema.SObjectField sobjectField = objectFields.get(fieldApiName);
            String objectDotField = objectApiName + '.' + fieldApiName;
            
            if (!fieldsWithPermReadTrue.contains(objectDotField)) {
                 FieldPermissions newFP = new FieldPermissions();
                 newFP.ParentId = INTEGRATION_BOT_PERMSET_ID;
                 newFP.SObjectType = objectApiName;
                 newFP.Field = objectDotField;
                 newFP.PermissionsRead = true;
                 fieldPermissionsForInsert.add(newFP);
            }
        }
    }
    Database.insert(fieldPermissionsForInsert, false);    
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    // execute any post-processing operations
}

}

The issue here is, no matter if you call it from a batch or non-batch process, you are doing all your logic in createFieldPermissions.
That means if you org has 2000 objects, and if every object has approx 10 fields then you create FieldPermissions for each fields under them which means 2000 * 10 = 20000 records being inserted as part of
Database.insert(fieldPermissionsForInsert, false);
which is not possible as Salesforce has a limit to insert 10000 records in one transaction.
You will need to insert fieldPermissionsForInsert in batches of 10000, or less.
Something like this would work in order to insert fieldPermissionsForInsert in batches.
/**
 * Created by Nagendra on 16-07-2024.
 */

public with sharing class PermissionSetUpdateBatch implements Queueable {

    List<FieldPermissions> allFieldPermissionsForInsert = null;
    Integer batchSize = null;

    public PermissionSetUpdateBatch(List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsForInsert, Integer batchSize) {
        this.allFieldPermissionsForInsert = fieldPermissionsForInsert;
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
    }


    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsForInsert = new List<FieldPermissions>();
        Integer recordsToProcess = Math.min(this.batchSize, this.allFieldPermissionsForInsert.size());

        for (Integer i = 0; i < recordsToProcess; i++) {
            fieldPermissionsForInsert.add(this.allFieldPermissionsForInsert[i]);
        }

        Database.insert(fieldPermissionsForInsert, false);
        // Log if something is failed so that you can check it later

        // Create a new list excluding the processed records
        List<FieldPermissions> remainingPermissions = new List<FieldPermissions>();
        for (Integer i = recordsToProcess; i < this.allFieldPermissionsForInsert.size(); i++) {
            remainingPermissions.add(this.allFieldPermissionsForInsert[i]);
        }

        // If there are still records to insert, enqueue the job again
        if (!remainingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(new PermissionSetUpdateBatch(remainingPermissions, this.batchSize));
        }
    }
}


Thank you Nagendra. I understand why it's erring. I don't know how to put the describe code in the batch. I'm used to putting soql in the start method,  not describe.

You technically dont need a batch, Lets keep batch for dealing with records in millions, Queueable would be more than enough, I will edit my post and share how to insert these fieldPermissionsForInsert  in batches from queueable

Thank you Nagendra

@RyanMcNeely I updated my post above. You can do all your logic before, but instead of inserting all at once, you can use System.enqueueJob(new PermissionSetUpdateBatch(fieldPermissionsForInsert, 10000));. The 10000 can be configured based on your preference. Also you can log if something has failed in the proceess.

This looks great! Trying it now. How do you determine when to use Queuable over Batch?

This would be totally personal preference and the logic running under the execute method. Batch can only run with a max of 2000 records in bachtes, but with recent enhancements in queueable + cursors, a queueable can run with batches of 50k records.
